# How can telnet connect to an arbitrary port?

Tags: telnet

Through `telnet` I am able to connect to any server at any port, how does it work? Is there a telnet server daemon running on that server?
If there is, shouldn't the daemon listen on a specific port? why can I connect to an arbitrary port on that server? 
Why can I telnet to `127.0.0.1` at `80` port and get a response from my Nginx without a telnet daemon running on my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `telnet` client doesn't do any special processing. It opens a TCP connection to the remote server on any port you specify, forwards through this connection anything you type and puts on screen anything that it receives from the server.

When you `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` it opens a connection to port `80` of `localhost` where usually a web server is already listening (`nginx` in your case).

An HTTP client knows how to craft an HTTP request and send it through the connection. The `telnet` client doesn't know anything about HTTP but if you know the protocol you can manually craft a request and type it and the `telnet` client will happily send it for you through the connection. If the program at the other end (the web server) understands the request it will send a response back. Again, the `telnet` client doesn't understand a bit of the response (it's just data to it) but it happily puts the response on screen.

You can use `telnet` to connect to any port of a (remote or local) computer, as long as there is a server application that is listening on that port.

There is a `telnet` server, it usually listens on port `23` if I remember correctly and when a connection is established to it it launches a pseudo-terminal program that handles a login session on the server (the exact program it launches to handle the session depends on the OS). If the login succeeds, the `telnet` client then talks with the pseudo-terminal program that passes the keys you type to a remote shell; the output produced by the shell goes back to you through the pseudo-terminal -> TCP connection -> telnet client.

The `telnet` server is deprecated by the SSH protocol that does the same thing (and many others) but everything that goes through the connection is encrypted on each end before sending and decrypted on the other end before being used. This adds privacy and security to the services already provided by the telnet server.

The `telnet` client, however, is still useful because it can be used to test the functionality of servers that use unencrypted text protocols like HTTP, SMTP, POP3, IMAP etc.

Comment: It feels a bit counterintuitive that the client does nothing more than opening a TCP connection. (After all, this is a telnet rather than a TCP client program). So just to confirm, is it that the telnet protocol has very little to do with data format during network transmission, but more about forwarding data into a pseudo-terminal at both the client and the server sides?

Comment: When it is used to connect to a telnet server, the telnet client talks the [telnet protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) to the server. Otherwise it is just a TCP client program, as you noticed.